# DI injecting a String bean as single element of a List<String> instead of the proper List<String> bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-4

I am learning Spring Framework and DI for the first time, and trying a little test app with Spring-boot 1.2.0 (project constraint due to Spring Framework version required to be 4.1.x), I made a BookBean that has two attributes: a String title and a List of authors. Apparently the DI is injecting the title as sole member of the list, and I'm absolutely clueless about why.

I added some logging on the methods marked @Bean to see when they are called plus the BookBean constructor, and I noticed the String method is called AFTER the constructor is invoked:

```
[2019-04-29 14:46:05.631] boot - 3888  INFO [main] --- CollectionConfig: returning title: [A sample book]
[2019-04-29 14:46:05.637] boot - 3888  INFO [main] --- BookBean: construction called
[2019-04-29 14:46:05.649] boot - 3888  INFO [main] --- CollectionConfig: returning authors: [[John, Adam, Harry]]
```

That leads me to believe that the DI doesn't have the List bean available when trying to construct the BookBean, and "does the next best thing", returning a List injected with the only String bean it knows: title.

In turn, that made me believe I might be doing the whole Autowired thingy the wrong way, and that I might be failing to line up the autowiring by type/name as requested. It is my understanding that the default autowire is by Type, and that the constructor should try and look for beans of two different types: String and List, but I tried annotating the beans with @Bean(name = "title"/"authors") to no success. If I also try to annotate the constructor parameters with @Qualifier("title"/"authors") I get the following error:

```
[2019-04-29 14:54:25.847] boot - 20824  INFO [main] --- CollectionConfig: returning title: [A sample book]
[2019-04-29 14:54:25.853] boot - 20824  WARN [main] --- AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookBean' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/dev/Repos/branches/branch_rest_remake/branch_2019_04_11/webapp/target/webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/company/spring/webapp/domain/BookBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [collection of java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=authors)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [collection of java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=authors)}
```

These are my classes: (EDIT - removed Logger instantiation from the example, but they are there on the code)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DummyController {
    @Autowired
    private BookBean bookBean;

    @RequestMapping("/di")
    String dummyDependencyInjection() {
        logger.info("called /di");
        return bookBean.printAuthors();
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class CollectionConfig {
    @Bean
    public String title() {
        String title = "A sample book";
        logger.info("returning title: ["+title+"]");
        return title;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<String> authors() {
        List<String> authors = Arrays.asList("John", "Adam", "Harry");
        logger.info("returning authors: ["+authors+"]");
        return authors;
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class BookBean {
    private String title;
    private List<String> authors;

    @Autowired
    public BookBean(String title, List<String> authors) {
        logger.info("construction called");
        this.title = title;
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    public String printAuthors() {
        logger.info("printAuthors called");
        return "Authors in "+ title + "\n"+authors;
    }
}
```

Without the @Qualifier annotations, the bean is built with title: "A sample book" and authors: ["A sample book"] when the actual value for authors should be: ["John", "Adam", "Harry"]

With the @Qualifier annotation, it just fails to boot up.

Comment: The problem is that you can create multiple beans from the same object, so you can use `@Autowire List<MyObject> objs` to get all beans for this type as list. For every `@Bean` a bean with the name of the method (if you don't specify it yourself), so you have to use that name if you want to access a single bean if you have multiple beans from the same type.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp indeed, I tried adding a second String bean, and DI is returning both "A sample title" and the new bean on the array, I was not aware of how lists worked by default. I read that using a Qualifier should work though, but that's evading me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `@Autowired` will try to find beans by type. In your `BookBean` class you are injecting a `String title` and a `List<String> authors`.

What does Spring do under the hood?

**String title** - it will find **a** Bean of type String ( if it finds more than one, it requires a @Qualifier to determine which one to inject ), in your case `@Bean String title()`

**List authors** - it will try to find **all** the Beans of type String, in your scenario you have only ony one: `title()`

To conclude, your `List<String> authors()` bean will not be accessible unless you use `@Resource(id ="authors")` to inject it.

Going a few steps back, you should never rely on primitives for dependency injection because they may mislead you. I would suggest to wrap them in some classes, a.k.a define a `Title` class and an `Authors` class **if** you really need to use dependency injection.

Comment: Indeed, @Resource worked like a charm. Only caveat  is that you can't use it with Constructor Injection, but other than that, it served its purpose. 

The primitive DI is a good hint, it would have probably solved this much faster, but I bogged on a little corner case.

Answer (score 1):

When a @Bean annotation is present on a typed collection or array, the bean will automatically be populated with all beans of that type registered by the application context (see [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)). In your case this is the `title` been (`A sample book`), so the `authors` list only contains that entry.

If you want to autowire the specific bean you can reference to the name using the [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation (see [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)).

In your case, the constructor can be rewritten as:

```
@Autowired
public BookBean(String title, @Qualifier("authors") List<String> authors) {
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = authors;
}
```

When using typed collections the [reference documentation actually suggests](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) (Scroll down a little bit just under the gray section). You to use the @Resource annotation:

```
private String title;

@Resource
private List<String> authors;

public BookBean(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

Comment: using the '@Qualifier on the constructor causes an error when booting up. Perhaps the Collection autowiring by qualifier is not available on Spring 4.1.x?

I have just been able to make it work, using the '@Resource annotation for the authors bean instead of '@Autowired, though sadly I had to part ways from the constructor injection, as '@Resource is only available at field at method level.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? For me the constructor works fine.

Comment: Same one I detailed on the post; too long to paste it here :(  

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [collection of java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=authors)};  

for constructor:
```@Autowired
 public BookBean(String title, @Qualifier("authors") List<String> authors) {...}
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the authors being a List<String> defined as a java @Bean instead of on an XML?

Comment: I editted my answer. Apparantly the documentation suggests using `@Resource` in this specific scenario. Although i find it weird that the `@Qualifier` works for me and not for you.

Comment: I found that @Resource actually works shortly before your reply and the other person's that suggested it. That actually works like a charm :) but you can't use it on the constructor injection.

Thanks a lot!